# How to get the current slide no in Glide.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, glidejs

Hi how can I get the current slide no when I click next and previous button in GLide.js http://glide.jedrzejchalubek.com/docs.html#intro.

```
var carousel = $('#Carousel').glide({
                type: 'carousel',
                startAt: 1,
                touchDistance: 2,
          afterInit:function(){console.log("paintSlider")},
          autoplay: 0
              });
console.log(carousel.current());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, the function `carousel.current()` is not working.

You can use the code's callback and events instead.
Example:

```
var carousel = $('#Carousel').glide({
            type: 'carousel',
            ...
            afterTransition : function(event) {
                console.log(event.index); // the current slide number
            } 
        });
```

Also, `carousel.index()` works too!

Answer (score 3):

```
 const glide = new Glide('.glide');

  glide.on(['mount.after', 'run'], () => {
    const currentIndex = glide.index;
    console.log(currentIndex)
   });

  glide.mount();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but documentation about accessing API is missing. I'll fix that.

You need to access api via `.data('glide_api')`, before making api calls.

```
var carousel = $('#Carousel').glide({
      type: 'carousel',
      startAt: 1,
      touchDistance: 2,
      afterInit:function(){console.log("paintSlider")},
      autoplay: 0
}).data('glide_api');

console.log(carousel.current());
```

Thanks for using plugin!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    var glide = jQuery('.slider').glide({
        afterTransition : function() {
            console.log(glide.current());
        } 
    }).data('api_glide'); // data('api_glide') to get opportunity to use glide.current()

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the property `index` on your glide instance.

For example:

```js
import Glide, { Controls } from '@glidejs/glide/dist/glide.modular.esm';

var glider = new Glide( el, options );

glider.mount( {
  Controls,
} );

// You can get the current index using glider.index;
console.log( glider.index );
```

Answer (score 0):

Glibert answer works

```html
var stGlide = new Glide(`.heroglide-${article.id}`, {
          type: 'carousel',
          animationDuration: 500,
          startAt: 1,
          perView: 1,
          peek: {
              before: 50,
              after: 50
          },
        //   afterTransition : function(event) {
        //     console.log("========transition",event.index); // the current slide number
        // } 
          }); 
          try{
         
          stGlide.on(['mount.after', 'run'], () => {
            const currentIndex = stGlide.index;
            console.log("====>index==>",currentIndex)
           
           });

         
            stGlide.mount();
          }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const glide = new Glide('.glide');

glide.on("run", () => {
   console.log(slider.index);
});
```